# Filtering a cursor with WHERE condition

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to filter the contacts list by modifying the selection of my cursor when an OnTextChange happens in my EditText. The problem: the list stays as it is, i.e. it does not get updated as per the filter. What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's my sql query (specifically GLOB part)?

```
digitsText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
    filterText = digitsText.getText().toString();
    WHERE_CONDITION = ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + " GLOB '*" + filterText + "*'";
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(URI, PROJECTION, WHERE_CONDITION, null, SORT_ORDER);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
});
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what's actually going wrong. Not getting results? Error messages?

Comment: By the way: letting user input go through to the database unfiltered is *bad*. Recall Bobby Tables?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - the list stays as it is, i.e. it does not get updated as per the filter. Thanks for the db input tip :) i do constrain input to only digits and coupe special characters, so no worries there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you generate a new `Cursor`, you do not actually do anything with it. You need to either:

- call `swapCursor()` on your `CursorAdapter`, if you are on API Level 11 or higher
- call `changeCursor()` on your `CursorAdapter` (which may be the better option anyway, if you will not be needing the old `Cursor`, as `changeCursor()` will close it for you)
- create a new `CursorAdapter` and call `setListAdapter()` using the new adapter

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try these hints!